# Buildroot packages not in busybox can't be run

Tags: buildroot, busybox

If I compile custom executables (binaries), or use executables from buildroot, busybox shell keeps saying `applet not found`  For instance, I can select `coremark` from the included packages list, but then if I try running coremark, I get:

```
~ # coremark
coremark: applet not found
```

Is there some setting within busybox or buildroot that tells busybox to be willing to load non-busybox executable files? I'm currently running with RISC-V 32-bit rv32 Linux 5.18 and tip of master buildroot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue!  On my particular system, only flat binaries are usable.  So, you either need to add `-Wl,-elf2flt=-r` to the link invocation or use `elf2flt` in order to make executable files.